# Auto play problem while using chrome HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with google chrome while playing this code. The audio file isn't working because of the new policy of chrome

```
 <audio autoplay loop>

        <source src="Test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Comment: Not really much you can do about it, Chrome changed its policy a while ago, see this link to learn more about it https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes . There was a neat trick to auto play using iframes but it is not working anymore.